Tkinter is showing dual screen even and I don't know how the other one came
This is the source code:
class CalcGUI(tkinter.Tk):
   FONT_MEDIUM = ('Calibre',10)
   FONT_MEDIUM = ('Calibre',7)


def __init__(self):  # As usual calling the init constructor
    super().__init__() # super constructor is defined
    
    self.screen = Tk()
    self.screen.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    self.screen.title("Calculator")


    self.screen.geometry("312x321")

    thm = ttk.Style()
    thm.theme_use('clam')

    self.input_field = Entry(self.screen,width = 312)
    self.input_field.grid(column = 0, row =0 )
    self.input_field.grid(ipady=5)

    self.screen.mainloop()

This is the dual screen that's popping.(https://i.sstatic.net/BH34Ywaz.png)
The screen with calculator title is the one I defined but I don't know where the other. The tk titled screen has no widget, so how is it even showing anything?
I tried rewriting and the same problem rises

CalcGUI already inherits from Tk, why do you create another instance of Tk inside the __init__()? Also don't post image of code. Paste the code directly into the question.

@acw1668 has answered the question. Don't inherit from Tk if you want to create an object again.

And why are you creating two class variables FONT_MEDIUM?

CalcGUI inherits from tkinter.Tk, so when you create an instance of this class get a root window. In the constructor you do self.screen = Tk() which also creates a window. Thus, self is one window and self.screen is another.
You need to either remove all use of self.screen and just use self, or don't inherit from tkinter.Tk. Either method is fine and has advantages and disadvantages.
